# How to verify whether the placeholder is displayed after sending key inside Search field?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

in Selenium WebDriver - JAVA
I want to check whether placeholder is displayed or not after sending some text inside a search field.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "placeholder" attribute.

```
element.getAttribute("placeholder");
```

Upd. I just realised, that you're talking about *visibility*. It can be visible while text field is filled, only due to some css problem. But you can also check "value" attribute, it can help in some cases.